# How to print unicode charaters in Command Prompt with Ruby

Tags: ruby, unicode, command-prompt

I was wondering how to print unicode characters, such as Japanese or fun characters like .

I can print hearts with:

```
hearts = "\u2665"
puts hearts.encode('utf-8')
```

How can I print more unicode charaters with Ruby in Command Prompt?
My method works with some characters but not all.

Code examples would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: _"My method works with some characters but not all"_ – and what characters do not work?

Comment: @stefan, didnt work with many, basically only the suits from cards were working. The updated answer works good! I just tried it :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to enclose the unicode character in `{` and `}` *if the number of hex digits isn't 4 (credit : [/u/Stefan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/477037/stefan))* e.g.:

```
heart = "\u2665"
package = "\u{1F4E6}"
fire_and_one_hundred = "\u{1F525 1F4AF}"
puts heart
puts package
puts fire_and_one_hundred
```

Alternatively you could also just put the unicode character directly in your source, which is quite easy at least on macOS with the Emoji & Symbols menu accessed by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> by default (a similar menu can be accessed on Windows 10 by <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>;</kbd> ) in most applications including your text editor/Ruby IDE most likely:

[image: macOS Emoji Menu]

```
heart = "♥"
package = ""
fire_and_one_hundred = ""
puts heart
puts package
puts fire_and_one_hundred
```

**Output:**

```
♥
```

---

**How it looks in the macOS terminal**:

[image: How it looks in the macOS terminal]

Comment: _"You need to enclose the unicode character in { and }"_ – only if the number of hex digits isn't 4.

Comment: @Stefan Updated answer.

Comment: The code runs but I get a question mark character in a box in the command prompt.

Comment: @Adjam What operating system are you on? I added a screenshot of how it looks in the macOS terminal.

Comment: @shash678 This updated solution works much better! Great answer! It works on Ubuntu (my system)